# AES128 decryption error: javax.crypto.IlliegalBlockSizeException: input must be a multible of 16 when decrypting with a padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

When I encrypt text using AES128 it works fine, then when I try to decrypt using the same encrypted data and key it gives me a

> javax.crypto.IlliegalBlockSizeException: input must be a multible of
>   16 when decrypting with a padded cipher

error this only happens after my previous fix of adding an IvParameterSpec

AES128 Java Class:

```
package xcrypt;

    import java.security.SecureRandom;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class AES128 
    {

        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        private  byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception 
        {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(seed);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            return raw;
        }

        public  byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception 
        {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(raw), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
            return encrypted;
        }

        public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception 
        {

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(raw), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }
    }
```

here's where the methods are being called (main class):

```
public byte[] Encryption_AES128(byte[] plain  , byte[] key) throws Exception
    {
        AES128 aes128 = new AES128();
        return aes128.encrypt(key, plain);
    }
    public byte[] Decryption_AES128(byte[] cipher  , byte[] key) throws Exception
    {
        AES128 aes128 = new AES128();
        return aes128.decrypt(key, cipher);
    }
```

Comment: was it working fine before adding `IVParameter`?

Comment: no then it gave me a missing parameter error

Comment: can you show us the nearyby code where you are actually invoking your encryption and decryption methods?

Comment: An AES block is 128 bits, 16 bytes.  Check that your cyphertext `byte[]` is a multiple of 16 bytes long.  How long is your IV?  If it is not 16 bytes, then it is possible that is causing the problem.

Comment: Note that using `SecureRandom` to derive keys is not a good algorithm. Use PBKDF2 instead if you want to derive a key from a password. The `SecureRandom` implementation may differ across platforms, and setting the seed directly after creation may not work on each implementation either.

Comment: The code from the question works on my machine. @new-europe check if you are truncating the output of `Encryption_AES128` before passing it back into `Decryption_AES128`.